How to eliminate Voltage Spikes When Controlling 24V DC Motor
I am controlling a 24V DC motor (~100W, permanent magnet) using a low-side IRLB4030 MOSFET and a MIC5014 gate driver with a PWM signal from µC. The PWM signal at the MOSFET's gate is clean, but the drain-to-source voltage (ds) shows significant voltage spikes and oscillations during switching.
I am using the following components:

MOSFET: https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IRLB4030PBF/2096639
Flyback Diode: https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/diotec-semiconductor/SK4045CD2-3G/22190344
Gate Driver: https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/microchip-technology/MIC5014YM/1030119
Gate Resistor: 220 Ω
C1 = 1000 µF

Here is a screenshot of my setup:

Here is a screenshot of Vds measurement:

Here is another measurement after 10ms (after a while)

System Details:

PWM Freq.: ~33Hz (low freq.: to avoid temperature rise due to switching losses)
PMDC Motor (24V, ~100W)

I expected a clean and stable drain-to-source voltage waveform with minimal noise or ringing. I tried also with higher PWM Frequencies but it did not helped. My assumption is that this peak is coming from motor brake during PWM switch to off.
Questions:

What is the cause of voltage spike and oscillations?
Are the electronic components are correctly selected (are they compatible?)
How can I eliminate/reduce the voltage spike and oscillations?


The screenshot looks as if the polarity is reversed. Please confirm the setup.

I agree with the above. You also need to mark on where the 12 volt rail appears and show the gate drive voltage on another channel simultaneously.

Agreed, the trace looks upside down. I would expect those oscillations from motor commutation, near positive supply potential, not ground. The sharp spike, if due to motor inductance, should be upwards, and its severity would suggest a slow diode.

Thanks for the feedback. I made a new measurement.
Channel 1 (RED): V gate to source
Channel 2 (YELLOW): V drain to source

The question text says the MOSFET is in the high-side but the schematic shows a low-side MOSFET. Please clarify. Also please explain how measurements were taken. I'd like to see a zoom on the wiggle on the yellow trace, say 50µs/div, as its shape will give information.

sry, its wrong in the question. it is a low-side MOSFET, as shown in the schematic.
I measured with an oscilloscope using two probes: one connected to the MOSFET's gate and the other to the drain, with both probe grounds connected to the source pin of the MOSFET.

When the MOSFET switches off, the motor free-wheels, and the oscillations are simply the motor's EMF changing as its magnets sweep past the coils.
The spike is voltage kick resulting from the inductive coils trying to maintain coil current after being disconnected by the MOSFET. If the diode were not there, that voltage would spike much higher, perhaps to hundreds of volts. The good news is that diode is doing its job, preventing the drain from rising beyond the positive supply, and protecting the MOSFET.
Both these phenomena are normal, and shouldn't be considered a problem, per se, unless you are trying to obtain emissions certification. To suppress them entirely requires a push-pull (half-bridge) driver. You can slow the rise of the inductive spike with an RC snubber. The exact structure and component values for an effective snubber would depend entirely on characteristics of the motor.

Thank you :)
Do the voltage spikes and the oscillations have a negative impact on the motor's temperature and lifespan?

@ElGuerrero91 There's no current/torque while the motor is free-wheeling, so no mechanical stresses, or electrical heating. Mechanical torque/stress and heating occurs when the transistor is on, and current is flowing, which ironically is when you don't see these artefacts. Repeatedly applying and releasing torque is the biggest cause of stress, but that's the nature of PWM.


What is the cause of voltage spike and oscillations?

Replace the motor with a low-inductance dummy load. Then you'll know what comes from the circuit and its supply, and what is the motor's contribution.

How can I eliminate/reduce the voltage spike and oscillations?

By minimizing parasitic impedances, and adding a snubber. But don't be too concerned - you won't eliminate it all, and the only concern really is EMC, i.e. that the thing doesn't radiate too much junk. You care less about how these look, more about what the spectrum analyzer will pick up from the test antenna.

The vertical spike at MOSFET turn-off could be from the leakage inductance of the motor, adding 100nF or so in parallel with the motor may help that, Use a low resistance type like MLCC or metal film capacitor.
The ripple is the back emf of the motor.
In other words the spinning motor is acting as a generator and the ripple frequency indicates its commutation speed. The ripple voltage  which (is also proportional to speed) also increases (pushing the yellow drain voltage plot, closer to 0V)
If it's not a problem you don't need to do anything.
The motor is not braking (other than by friction)  during the PWM off period.

Thank you. I will try out if the spilkes will be reduces by adding a capacitor
